# while install the react-data-grid in project its styles not loaded but working fine in demo

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

While including react-data-grid in the project, the styles were not loaded.
I've tested it and it works fine when I created a single demo for it.

GridView.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import 'react-data-grid/lib/styles.css';
const columns = [
    { key: 'id', name: 'ID' },
    { key: 'title', name: 'Title' }
];

const GridView = () => {

    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

    const getCountries = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
                method: 'GET',
            }).then(res => res.json())
            setCountries(response);

        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("error =" + error);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getCountries();
    }, []
    );

    const rowKeyGetter = (row) => {
        console.log("DataGet: ", row);

        return row.id;
    }

    return <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={countries} rowKeyGetter={rowKeyGetter} />;

}

export default GridView;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "./GridView";
import DataGraph from "./Graph";
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import DatePicker, { DateObject } from "react-multi-date-picker"
import { useState } from 'react'



const options = [
    { value: 'one', className: 'mh-dropdown-option' },
    { value: 'two', className: 'mh-dropdown-option' },
    { value: 'two', className: 'mh-dropdown-option' },
    { value: 'two', className: 'mh-dropdown-option' },
    { value: 'two', className: 'mh-dropdown-option' },
]

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: null,
            key: 'selection'
        }
    ]);

    const [values, setValues] = useState([
        new DateObject().subtract(4, "days"),
        new DateObject().add(4, "days")
    ])




    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                <br></br>
                <DatePicker
                    value={values}
                    onChange={setValues}
                    range
                />
                <br></br>
                <div>
                    <Dropdown options={options} placeholder="User Activity: Who's Logged In" className='mh-select-container' controlClassName='mh-dropdown mh-dropdown-rounded' menuClassName='mh-dropdown-content' />
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <h2>My Chart</h2>
                <DataGraph />
                <br></br>
                <h2>My Grid</h2>
                <Grid />
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

webpack-dev.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './Reactsrc/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'report.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts'),
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                  }
                },
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'Reactsrc')
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[image: Its showing like this not loaded css]

Its showing like this not loaded css. I also install the style loader using npm install --save-dev style-loader but not fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In GridView.js file Instead Of this ,

```
 const rowKeyGetter = (row) => {
    console.log("DataGet: ", row);

    return row.id;
}

return <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={countries} rowKeyGetter={rowKeyGetter} />;
```

You should try this:

```
 const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);
 return <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} onRowsChange={setRows} />;
```